# Duplicate javascripts are getting loaded ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, duplicates, multiple-instances

I'm developing a web based document management for my final year project. The user interacts with only one page and the respective pages will be called using AJAX when the user click the respective tabs (Used tabs for navigation).

Due to multiple user levels (admin, managers, etc.) I've put the javascripts into the correspondent web pages.

When user requests the user request everythings work perfectly except some situations where some functions are triggered multiple times. I found the problem. It is each time the user clicks a tab it loads same scripts as new instance and both of them will be triggered when I call a function.

to load the content I tired

`.load` and `$.ajax();` non of them address the issue.

[image: This is how Firebug shows]

I tried to put all into the main page at that time my jQueryUI does not work. I tired

```
$(document).load('click', $('#tab_root li'), function(){});
```

Same issue remain.

Can anyone help me out this issue?

**--Edit--**

```
    $(function){
        $(document).on('click','#tabs',function(e){
            getAjax($(this))
        });

    }

    //method to load via AJAX
    function getAjax(lst){
        var cont = $(lst).text();
        $.ajax({
            url:'../MainPageAjaxSupport',
            data: {
                "cont":cont
            },
            error: function(request, status, error){
                if(status==404){
                    $('#ajax_body').html("The requested page is not found. Please try again shortly");      
                }
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#ajax_body').html(data);
            },

        });


    }
```

Comment: Try using `bind` instead of click , that way you can `unbind` the event . Or if you are creating the elements dynamically , use `on`

Comment: I've tried .on but it didn't work.Same multiple occurrences.

Comment: how about bind and unbind . Also , posting your code here or on JSFiddle might help us help you!

Comment: @harsha I done bind just now, but issue remains.

Comment: Where is the Code??!!

Comment: @harsha I've updated my question with the code. Sorry that I couldn't update it in JSFiddle as my code is so complex and huge.

Comment: How do you include the java script? Is it inline or a separate file ?

Comment: Do you mean all functions trigger twice? Or just those bound to events? If it's all functions that would be strange indeed.

Comment: @Kaan Not all function. For an example I use a table to add package list (about product). and there which adds new row after the last row of the table. It works perfectly but when I click the button thereafter it works double time. PS: In this scenario I tracked the javascript got duplicated on my every click on the tab.

Comment: Yes those would be events. Check my modified answer. The new solution at the top ought to be the best for your needs.

Comment: If you got an solution please let me know, i have the same problem, to each fetch the script tags are loading too, and the previous articles by clicking them, same function is running that much time as the fetch is made!

Answer (score 1):

You can't undo JavaScript after it has been executed by simply unloading the file or removing the script element.

The best solution would probably be to set a variable in each JavaScript file you include in your ajax data and include them from an online inline JavaScript inside the ajax data along with a conditional like such:

```
<script>
    if(!tab1Var) $.getScript("filename");
<script>
```

#### Older Solutions

You can manually unbind each event before setting them with off.

```
$(function){
        $('#tabs').off('click');
        $('#tabs').on('click',function(e){
            getAjax($(this));
        });
}
```

Alternatively you can initialize a global variable (eventsBound1=false) for each tab in the main html:

```
$(function){
    if(!eventsBound1){
        $('#tabs').on('click', function(e){
            getAjax($(this));
        });
        eventsBound1 = true;
    }
}
```

The tabs click event is only an example you have to do this for each time you bind an event in the scripts that are being reloaded.

if all the events are bound to things inside ajax_body, a final thing you can try is:

```
success: function(data){
    $('#ajax_body').empty();
    $('#ajax_body').html(data);
},
```

Comment: it didn't work. If I can able to remove the older javascript file which were loaded previously before getAjax($(this)); function triggers then I hope the issue will be rectified.(Check my picture in the question)

Comment: @Sumer Is the JavaScript in the data passed to the ajax call you posted? then try the third solution I posted.

Comment: I'm sorry it failed again. Sure it $('#ajax_body').empty() worked, but the issue is the loaded javascript remains in the browser cache. So the second time when I request the SAME TAB instead of replacing the older javascript it produces a new javascript.

Comment: Is your JavaScript in a separate file?

Comment: External file and the above code is written in a common javascript file & loaded in the main page.

Comment: So data contains no JavaScript?

Comment: Data returns an html page and it is customized for each and every levels of users. The functions are different therefore YES data contain the javascripts as well.

Comment: @Sumer Well then you have to apply one of the first two solutions above to each time you bind an event in the tabs. I assume the multiple events that are firing are bound to things outside of the part you are replacing otherwise the third solution should work. If you use the second solution define different globals in the main html for each tab. You can't unload JavaScript after it has been executed.

Comment: Is that so. I'll try it and let you know about the status. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have bind an event click on 'document' so getAjax() only replace the '#ajax_body' not the 'document'.

This means old event is still attached to the 'document' all you need is to unbind event by using `$(document).off('click');` or change 'document' to other elements.